# cant make the edit button to function

Tags: javascript, json, function, dom, edit

i have written this code for javascript to do list  project but i cant make the edit button to function

the edit task button appears in the task but it is not working at all, i want it to let me edit the task and to save the updated task in local storge,here is the full code:

```
function addTask() {
    const arrayTasks = getArrayFromStorage();
    const newTask = getNewTask();
    arrayTasks.push(newTask);
    saveToLocalStorage(arrayTasks);  
}


function getArrayFromStorage() {
    let arrayTasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks"));
    if (arrayTasks === null) {
        arrayTasks = [];
    }
    return arrayTasks;
}

function getNewTask() {
    const taskInput = document.getElementById("taskInput");
    const task = taskInput.value;

    const descriptionInput = document.getElementById("descriptionInput");
    const description = descriptionInput.value;

    const dateInput = document.getElementById("dateInput");
    const date = dateInput.value;

    const timeInput = document.getElementById("timeInput");
    const time = timeInput.value;

    const spanTask = document.getElementById("spanTask");
    const spanText = document.getElementById("spanText");
    const spanDate = document.getElementById("spanDate");
    const spanTime = document.getElementById("spanTime");
    spanTask.innerText = "";
    spanText.innerText = "";
    spanDate.innerText = "";
    spanTime.innerText = "";

    return {
        task,
        description,
        date,
        time,
    };
}

function saveToLocalStorage(arrayTasks) {
    const taskInput = document.getElementById("taskInput");
    const task = taskInput.value;

    const descriptionInput = document.getElementById("descriptionInput");
    const description = descriptionInput.value;

    const dateInput = document.getElementById("dateInput");
    const date = dateInput.value;

    const timeInput = document.getElementById("timeInput");
    const time = timeInput.value;

    if (task === "") {
        alert("Fill in the task!");
        return;

    } else if (description === "") {
        alert("Fill in the description of the task!");
        return;
    }
    if (date === "") {
        alert("Fill in the date");
        return;

    } else if (time === "") {
        alert("Fill in the time!");
        return;
    } else {

        localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(arrayTasks));     
    }
    listOfTasks.value = "";

    taskInput.value = "";
    descriptionInput.value = "";
    dateInput.value = "";
    timeInput.value = "";

    displayToUi();
}

function displayToUi() {
    const arrayTasks = getArrayFromStorage();

    const listOfTasks = document.getElementById("listOfTasks");

    listOfTasks.innerHTML = displayFromStorage(arrayTasks);


}

function displayFromStorage(arrayTasks) {
    if (arrayTasks.length === 0) {
        return '';
    }

    let list = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < arrayTasks.length; i++) {

        
        list += `<li id="li-${i}" class="hover">
            <div class="buttonDelete">
            <button onclick="deleteTask(${i})"
            id="button-${i}" class="close-button">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span> 
            </button>
            </div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-${i}" class="taskCheckbox" onchange="updateTaskStatus(${i}, this.checked)">
            <p class="taskListItem">
            ${arrayTasks[i].task} 
            </p>
            <p class="descriptionListItem">
            ${arrayTasks[i].description} 
            </p>
            <p class="dateListItem">
            ${arrayTasks[i].date}
            </p>
            <p class="timeListItem">
            ${arrayTasks[i].time}
            </p>
            <button onclick="editTask(${i})" id="editButton-${i}" class="edit-button">Edit</button>
            </li/>`;

            }
       
    
    return list;
}

function editTask(id) {
    const arrayTasks = getArrayFromStorage();
    const task = arrayTasks[id];

    
    const taskInput = document.getElementById("taskInput");
    const descriptionInput = document.getElementById("descriptionInput");
    const dateInput = document.getElementById("dateInput");
    const timeInput = document.getElementById("timeInput");

    taskInput.value = task.task;
    descriptionInput.value = task.description;
    dateInput.value = task.date;
    timeInput.value = task.time;

    localStorage.setItem("editTaskIndex", id);

    
    const updateButton = document.getElementById("updateButton");
    updateButton.onclick = updateEditedTask;

  }
 
function deleteTask(id) {
    const arrayTasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks"));

    arrayTasks.splice(id, 1);

    localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(arrayTasks));

    const listOfTasks = document.getElementById("listOfTasks");
    
    displayToUi();
     
}

function cleanForm() {
    const taskInput = document.getElementById("taskInput");
    const descriptionInput = document.getElementById("descriptionInput");
    const dateInput = document.getElementById("dateInput");
    const timeInput = document.getElementById("timeInput");

    taskInput.value = "";
    descriptionInput.value = "";
    dateInput.value = "";
    timeInput.value = "";

    const spanTask = document.getElementById("spanTask");
    const spanText = document.getElementById("spanText");
    const spanDate = document.getElementById("spanDate");
    const spanTime = document.getElementById("spanTime");
    spanTask.innerText = "";
    spanText.innerText = "";
    spanDate.innerText = "";
    spanTime.innerText = "";
}


function loadStorage() {
    let arrayTasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks"));

    if (!arrayTasks) {
        return;
    }
        const ul = document.getElementById("listOfTasks");
        ul.innerHTML = displayFromStorage(arrayTasks); 


        for (let i = 0; i < arrayTasks.length; i++) {
        const deleteButton = document.getElementById(`button-${i}`); 
        deleteButton.onclick = function(){
            deleteTask(i);
        }
           localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(arrayTasks));
    }


}
```

i would really be grateful for your help i cant find the problem, i tried diffrent ways but it does not work

Comment: Please edit your question and include the HTML.

Comment: You're missing the code for `updateEditedTask`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.